# How to create different number of columns layout by using flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to create a layout which has four rows. The first two rows have four columns. The third row and fourth row have only two columns.

I want the columns width are even distributed. So for the 4 columns, each of is 25% width stretch. For the two columns, each of takes 50% width. But there is gutter among the columns. The gutter's width is given say 25px. I can't get it work by flex. My some css code

```
.four-columns {
 display: flex;
 background-color: #b6701e;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

My html code:

```
 <div class="four-columns">
  <div>First Quarter</div>
  <div>Second Quarter</div>
  <div>Third Quarter</div>
  <div>Fourth Quarter</div>
</div>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/ardmore/pen/BaQPRQb)

**UPDATE:**

If I added `justify-content: space-evenly;` the column width are still not same. And for the two columns, I want the width is 50% and consider the gutter(margin)

Comment: this site has a great overview of how to use Flexbox... if you take the time to read it, you should have a good understanding of Flexbox after: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with flex, but the gutters make it a bit complicated, because the `gap` property isn't yet supported for flex in some browsers.

Can you use Grid? That makes this all pretty easy:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
}

.container > div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
  background-color: #b6701e;
}

/* change column layout for last two rows */
.container > div:nth-last-child(-n + 2) {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

body {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 150%;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 2px #b6701e;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div>
    <div>First Quarter</div>
    <div>Second Quarter</div>
    <div>Third Quarter</div>
    <div>Fourth Quarter</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input>
    <input>
    <select>
      <option value="0">Select car:</option>
      <option value="1">Audi</option>
      <option value="2">BMW</option>
      <option value="3">Citroen</option>
      <option value="4">Ford</option>
      <option value="5">Honda</option>
      <option value="6">Jaguar</option>
      <option value="7">Land Rover</option>
      <option value="8">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="9">Mini</option>
      <option value="10">Nissan</option>
      <option value="11">Toyota</option>
      <option value="12">Volvo</option>
    </select>
    <select>
      <option value="0">Select car:</option>
      <option value="1">Audi</option>
      <option value="2">BMW</option>
      <option value="3">Citroen</option>
      <option value="4">Ford</option>
      <option value="5">Honda</option>
      <option value="6">Jaguar</option>
      <option value="7">Land Rover</option>
      <option value="8">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="9">Mini</option>
      <option value="10">Nissan</option>
      <option value="11">Toyota</option>
      <option value="12">Volvo</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>First Quarter</div>
    <div>Second Quarter</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input>
    <input>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I am not family with grid. So how did you consider the gutter 25 px in your css? I saw `grid-row-gap: 5px`. how is it related or computed? Also I want the text left aligned.

Comment: `grid-row-gap` and `grid-column-gap` set the gutters. Add `text-align: left` to `.container`.

Comment: `grid-row-gap` and `grid-column-gap` are now deprecated for `row-gap` and `column-gap`. You can access both my simply using `gap`